# Database still reports 600GB after removing 500GB File

Tags: sql-server, datafile, filegroups

I have a database with three files

- Log
- Primary Data File
- Blob Data file

the database was becoming too big to manage (600GB) so we removed the blob data (500GB) into FileStorage outside the DB.

we then dropped and recreated the Tables into the Primary datafile, following that we ran

```
Alter Database (db) Remove_File (Blob_Data)
```

Then ran

```
DBCC ShrinkDatabase ('db',10)
```

. As well as a few other shrinks database properties is still reporting the database size as 600GB.

```
sys.database_files
```

still remembers the file but it is in the status of 'Offline',

```
sys.sysfiles
```

has no mention of the file.

we are currently rebuilding indexes following the shrink, and intend to test the backup and restore process to see if the speed of backup / restore is affected by this.

is this something we need to be worried about?
is there any resolution to this?

Comment: we did come across the following article which explains the exact same issue https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8e4d2c55-3662-42a6-bbe7-f6f31fa3e471/dropped-filegroupfiles-still-show-up-in-sysmasterfiles-and-msdbdbobackupfile?forum=sqldatabaseengine it would appear a log backup resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql) for `sys.database_files`:

| Column name | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| is_name_reserved | bit | 1 = Dropped file name (name or physical_name) is reusable only after the next log backup. When files are dropped from a database, the logical names stay in a reserved state until the next log backup. This column is relevant only under the full recovery model and the bulk-logged recovery model. 0 = The file name is unavailable for reuse. |
| create_lsn | numeric(25,0) | Log sequence number (LSN) at which the file was created. |
| drop_lsn | numeric(25,0) | LSN at which the file was dropped. |

Under the *full* or *bulk logged* recovery models, the reservation will be removed with the next log backup. Until then, the files will appear to be part of the database and reported in space used by some tools.